# I am having trouble with class System.String Represents text as a series of unicode characters. C#

Tags: c#, unicode

I am trying to get a Database to work and I am having trouble with my code.

My code is:

```
namespace Books.Entities
{
 public class Book
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [**StringLength**(255)]
     public string Title { get; set; }

     public Genere Category { get; set; }
   } 
}
```

The strength length gives me an error of 'Books.Entities.StringLengthAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

So make sure that you have referenced the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assembly and then:

```
[Required]
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute.StringLengthAttribute(255)]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

It appears that you have declared some custom `StringLengthAttribute` class in your `Books.Entities` namespace and which is conflicting with the original one. I guess you did this in an attempt to reference the system attribute.

Once you get rid of your custom StringLengthAttribute and added `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to your file you will be able to shorten your code to:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(255)]
public string Title { get; set; }
```